# User input include

Tags: php

This is pretty darn safe right? Something I've missed?

```
$page = sprintf("%s/%s.php", "pages", $_GET['page']);
if (file_exists($page)) {
    include $page;
}
else {
    echo "The page '$page' does not exist =(";
}
```

(yes you can use it)

Comment: You probably want to remove slashes, spaces, dots, or anything that can be used as a directive in the file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "better" way to do this is to have an array of the allowed pages, then do something like this:

```
$page = $_GET['page'] . '.php';
if(in_array($page, $all_pages)) {
    include('pages/' . $page);
}
```

You could easily get a list of all allowed pages by doing something like this:

```
$all_pages = glob('pages/*.php');
```

Documentation: [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array), [`glob`](http://www.php.net/glob)

Answer (score 4):

It's unsafe since a user can arbitrarily load whatever page they feel like.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure there's no `/` or `..` in `$_GET['page']`, and that the visitor is allowed to view any php file in the `pages` dir, i think it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Use [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)() to make sure there's no path information being supplied :

```
$page = sprintf("%s/%s.php", "pages", basename($_GET['page']));
if (file_exists($page)) {
        include $page;
}
else {
        echo "The page '$page' does not exist =(";
}
```